# Image sprite with data-lazy

Tags: html, lazy-loading, slick.js

I'm using a script called slick. Its an image carousel that's pretty nifty.
Just wondering if id be able to use an image sprite with the lazy load method it uses in the below example.
If so, how would i code it in there.

```
<div><a href="page.htm"><img class="slide_cats" data-lazy="image.jpg"/></a></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, by using a sprite image, it means your sprite holds several images and in order to show one image you use the sprite as a background image with a defined height, width and background-position. So images tags are irrelevant, and since in slick slider the data-lazy attribute is only for image tags - the answer is no.

Comment: Well that's disappointing. Now i have to figure out whether to keep the lazy load or remove it and replace with a sprite. Not sure if saving on connections or file size is better here.

Comment: generally speaking, sprites are best for small images and icons and not for big images. The main reason for that is that if you have many big images, it's better downloading them in parallel and not one at a time. Wanna share the parameters? How many images? what are their sizes?

Comment: Depends on the category really. This one would be 6 images at around 4-6kb each. Other category's may have 10 or so images.

Comment: 4-6kb should be considered a small file so I guess using sprites would be perfomance-wise

Comment: I might ditch the lazy load and go with sprites